# Unable to implement the listener

Tags: javascript

```
YAHOO.namespace("yuibook.calendar"); 

//define the lauchCal function which creates the calendar 
YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal = function() { 

    //create the calendar object, specifying the container 
    var myCal = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("mycal"); 

    //draw the calendar on screen 
    myCal.render(); 
}

//define the showCal function which shows the calendar
Var showCal = function() { 
    //show the calendar 
    myCal.show(); 
} 

//create calendar on page load
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal); 

//attach listener for click event on calendar icon 
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("calico", "click", showCal); 

//myCal.hide();
```

The problem with the code is that i am not able to display the calender when i click the icon. can anybody help. I am knew to this listener

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `myCal` variable is undefined in the `showCal` function. The `myCal` variable is defined in the `launchCal` function and is only available from within the scope of that function. You'll need to store a reference to your `myCal` variable.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
YAHOO.namespace("yuibook.calendar");

YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
    YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.myCal = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("mycal");
    YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.myCal.render();

    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("calico", "click", YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.myCal.show); 
});
```

Have a look at [this Popup Calendar example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/popup.html) from the YUI documentation for more details.